# Axios request in react for handling http request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

Axios request in react

here is my custom hooks but i am not getting how to attach spinner while waiting for response
I added loading and set it to true further i am notable to resolve it

```
const useHttpReqHandler = () => {
    const [result, setResult] = useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    const apiMethod = async ({url , data , method}) => {
        let options = {
            method,
            url,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
            data
        };
        let response = await axios(options);
        const UpdatedData = await response.data;
        console.log(UpdatedData)
        setResult(UpdatedData);
        setLoading(false)
    }

    return [result , apiMethod];
};
```

I am calling this custom hooks under another component

But how can i add Sppiner while the wait time for response

Comment: show your spinner code

Comment: return `loading` from the hook as well.

Comment: hi @Eugen Sunic I am not able to attach spinner code where should i attach i am confusing with the logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const useHttpReqHandler = () => {
    const [result, setResult] = useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const apiMethod = useCallback(async ({url , data , method}) => {
        let options = {
            method,
            url,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
            data
        };

        setLoading(true);


        try {
          let response = await axios(options);
          const UpdatedData = await response.data;
          setResult(UpdatedData);

          setLoading(false);
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e)
          setLoading(false);
        }

    }, [setLoading, setResult])

    return [loading, result , apiMethod];
};
```

And then show a spinner in your component while `loading` is `true`.

Untested and probably not working, but you might get the idea:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [loading, apiResult,  apiMethod] = useHttpReqHandler();


    const captchValidation = useCallback(() => {
        const x = result.toString();
        const y = inputValue.toString();

        apiMethod({url: 'your url', data: {"email": email}, method: 'post'})

        if (x === y) {
            console.log("Entered here in api part")
            if(apiResult){
             alert("success")
            }
        }
        else {
             alert("fail")
        }
    }, [apiMethod, apiResult])

    return (
        <>
            {
                loading ? (<Spinner />) : (<button onClick={captchValidation}></button>)
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi @Lekoaf I am confused how to use this hooks inside function captchValidation() which i mentioned  in question

Comment: You can't use Hooks inside utility functions. It has to be a React Component.

Comment: Added a rough example.

Comment: The rough example is working fine thanks a lot boss @Lekoaf but compilation error throws this React Hook useCallback has missing dependencies: 'email', 'inputValue', and 'result'. Either include them or remove the dependency array

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea where you got those from. I didn't really remove anything from your code. It's up to you to fit them in there somehow.

Comment: can i add spinner for few seconds only?

Comment: Does your request take more than a few seconds?

Comment: Yes a few second

Comment: Hi @Lekoaf even on fail case  that is in this part else { alert("fail") } spinner is running how should i stop it? any idea

Comment: You should probably wrap your Axios stuff in a try / catch and do `setLoading(false)` at the end of both of them. And don't use `alert`, use `console.log` instead.

Comment: can you give a small demo in your code as i had started react last week only

Comment: Thankyou so much @Lekoaf

Comment: Hi @Lekoaf  never goes inside this block ```            if(apiResult){
             alert("success")
            }``` never prints alert message rest everything is working fine

Comment: Yeah, I'm not going to debug your code for you. I did a best effort with the information I had from you. Maybe x === y never is true? What do I know. Try logging `apiResult` and see if includes what you think it should.